# How to define array for user input?

Tags: arrays, fortran, user-input, gfortran

I am very new to fortran ( i believe it is fortran90)

I a trying to create a program using arrays that lists the square root of numbers 1 through N, N being the user input. My goal is to have the first array of just numbers 1-N and then a second array of the equivalent square root of each number from the list. I attached what i assumed would work as well as the errors I'm getting.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZriXU.png)[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ad5rS.png)

Any help would be appreciated! :)

Comment: Please do not show code, program text output and error messages as pictures. Copy and paste them *as text*. It is very important for them to be searcheable. Especially for people with a similar problem. Please see [ask] and [mcve].

Comment: Your error message (delete the picture and copy and paste te text!) suggests that you failed to declare `N` as `integer`. To say anything more younmust show your code. Paste it here as text.